# Coonvert an array to a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 21 ) )
```

I need it to be convert it to a string to echo it out and to use it as a variable. How can I do that? I need only the `id`.

I was trying to use `implode('', $this_array);` , adding `(string)` before this array, but does not help...

Comment: You want the `id` only?

Comment: Yes I do want the id only

Comment: try `echo $this_array[0]['id'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do -

```
$id = $this_array[0]['id'];
echo $id;
```

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot. I am just not good in arrays, especially multidimensional, so I have tried more complex variants